# Resampling data and counting samples

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm having a bit of trouble with this function. The output isn't making sense to me, and perhaps there's a better way to do it?

```
def resample1min(df):
    # resamples into 1 min bins (post-marked), counts the number of available values within the 1 min period
    # this is due to the way the LiDAR and mast data is stored        

    df_result_1minavg = df.resample('1min', how='mean', closed='right', label='right')

    avail = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1min', closed='right', label='right'))['hspeed'].apply(lambda x: (~np.isnan(x)).count())
    avail.name = "avail"
    df_result_1minavg = pd.concat([df_result_1minavg, avail], axis=1)

    return df_result_1minavg
```

Basically, I need to resample the raw data (every 24 seconds) into 1 minute bins, and count how many (valid) hspeed values are within the bins. So far, the resampling works fine but not the 'avail' calculation.

For example, here is some raw output:

```
30/04/2014 18:15    6.142705482 -4.973648083    7.938508677 308.9965255
30/04/2014 18:15    5.515934842 -5.22163357 7.628816391 313.4299983
30/04/2014 18:15    5.820077951 -5.336002619    7.930640318 312.5154279
30/04/2014 18:16    6.108619196 -5.495682719    8.253005862 311.9764602
30/04/2014 18:16    5.815988388 -5.421155709    7.985682142 312.987661
30/04/2014 18:17    5.951908553 -5.299767675    8.004489122 311.6828797
30/04/2014 18:17    6.007600178 -5.284258473    8.036053689 311.3347153
30/04/2014 18:17    5.879259541 -5.345762306    7.981146823 312.2789224
```

Everything looks good!  But then in the 1 minute resampled output it says there are 6 samples within 18:16! This can't be right as the scans are 24 seconds each. Any idea of what is going wrong?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Worked OK for me (I had one row per minute). You might want to be more explicit about everything here.  Input data (including column names, dtypes), how you call function, what output you are seeing.

Comment: @JohnE the function call: 
`df_result_1minavg = resample1min(df_result_all)`
The resampling into 1 min bins works on my end, but I get unusual values for the availability (count of samples within the bins). Is this working on your side? The columns are DateTime (index), v, u, hspeed, dir. Thanks for the help!